# sending parameters with json in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsmutableurlrequest, urlsession

I'm trying to use webapi in my code. my JSON service has odata filtering. But when I try to send my link into my JSON serializer, I get "nil" response at myURL2. But if I send without parameter it works fine. Do you have any suggestions? How can I use ODATA in my code?

```
        let link = "https://apiservices.domain.com/api/Events?$filter=EventDate gt datetime'2018-02-01' and EventDate lt datetime'2018-02-15'"

        let myURL2 = NSURL(string: link)
        let request2 = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL2 as! URL)
        request2.httpMethod = "GET"


        request2.addValue("Bearer "+tokenNewId, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request2.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request2.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request2 as URLRequest) {(data2, response2, error2) -> Void in
            if let unwrappedData2 = data2 {
                do {
                    guard let records = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData2, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]] else {
                        return
                    }
           }
```

Comment: `...$filter=EventDate gt datetime'2...` The spaces may cause the issue. Could you check `url` then?

Comment: when i execute this link at postman, i get response

Comment: My bad, wasn't explicit, could you check the value of `myURL2` then?

Comment: Postman must percent-escape the URL before sending it. Spaces are most definitely not legal in URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let urlwithPercentEscapes = link.addingPercentEncoding( 
withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let myURL2 = NSURL(string: urlwithPercentEscapes!)
```

Comment: Spaces are not legal in URLs. Since your URL contains spaces, each space character must be escaped as `%20`. That's what this answer does, and why it work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that your url is not percent-encoded. You need to use the [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc) method to do that.

[Here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/) is a post that shows you how to do it.